# THREE.JS | Delaunator.JS THREE.BufferGeometry UV mapping

Tags: three.js, delaunay, uv-mapping, buffer-geometry

That's really weird, but I couldn't find any solution for uv mapping Delaunator.JS outputs.
Let's say I have a very basic set of points defined by:

```
for(var z = -512; z <= 512; z += 256){
    for(var x = -512; x <= 512; x += 256){
        
        points.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, 0, z));
        
    }  
}
   
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(512, 0, -384));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(128, 0, 512));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(384, 0, 512));
```

While, subdivision points go after, I need to process these points through Delaunator.JS in order to to build be able to generate a THREE.BufferGeometry plane.

[image]

Them I'm trying to generate UV map by:

```
for(var i = 0; i < indexDelaunay.triangles.length; i += 3){

var a = new THREE.Vector3(points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i]].x, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i]].y, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i]].z);
var b = new THREE.Vector3(points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 2]].x, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 1]].y, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 1]].z);
var c = new THREE.Vector3(points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 1]].x, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 2]].y, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 2]].z);

a.x = remapFloat(a.x, -512, 512, 0, 1);
a.z = remapFloat(a.z, -512, 512, 1, 0);

b.x = remapFloat(b.x, -512, 512, 0, 1);
b.z = remapFloat(b.z, -512, 512, 1, 0);

c.x = remapFloat(c.x, -512, 512, 0, 1);
c.z = remapFloat(c.z, -512, 512, 1, 0);

var mm = {min: {x: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, z: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY}, max: {x: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, z: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY} }

mm.min.x = Math.min(mm.min.x, a.x, b.x, c.x);
mm.min.z = Math.min(mm.min.z, a.z, b.z, c.z);

mm.max.x = Math.max(mm.max.x, a.x, b.x, c.x);
mm.max.z = Math.max(mm.max.z, a.z, b.z, c.z);

quad_uvs.push(mm.min.x, mm.min.z, mm.max.x, mm.max.z);
```

}

```
uvs = new Float32Array(quad_uvs);
geometry.setAttribute( 'uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );
```

The output is glitchy, meaning that I'm doing something wrong:

[image]

The output should be like this:

[image]

The code is attached.

```js
var texture = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
    
    
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, loader, terrain, glsl, uniforms, root, tree;
    
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xDEDEDE);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = "";

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 51200);
camera.position.set(-3072, 2048, -3072);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

controls.minDistance = 8;
controls.maxDistance = 10240;
    
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
    
//simple pseudo quadtree
var points = [], indices = [], quad_uvs = [], groups = [], materials = [];

for(var z = -512; z <= 512; z += 256){
    for(var x = -512; x <= 512; x += 256){
        
        points.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, 0, z));
        
    }  
}
   
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(512, 0, -384));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(128, 0, 512));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(384, 0, 512));
    
//delaunay
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
var indexDelaunay = Delaunator.from(points.map(v => { return [v.x, v.z]; }) );
var meshIndex = [], quad_uvs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < indexDelaunay.triangles.length; i++){ meshIndex.push(indexDelaunay.triangles[i]); }
        
for(var i = 0; i < indexDelaunay.triangles.length; i += 3){
    
    var a = new THREE.Vector3(points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i]].x, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i]].y, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i]].z);
    var b = new THREE.Vector3(points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 2]].x, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 1]].y, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 1]].z);
    var c = new THREE.Vector3(points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 1]].x, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 2]].y, points[indexDelaunay.triangles[i + 2]].z);
    
    a.x = remapFloat(a.x, -512, 512, 0, 1);
    a.z = remapFloat(a.z, -512, 512, 1, 0);
    
    b.x = remapFloat(b.x, -512, 512, 0, 1);
    b.z = remapFloat(b.z, -512, 512, 1, 0);
    
    c.x = remapFloat(c.x, -512, 512, 0, 1);
    c.z = remapFloat(c.z, -512, 512, 1, 0);
    
    var mm = {min: {x: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, z: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY}, max: {x: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, z: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY} }
    
    mm.min.x = Math.min(mm.min.x, a.x, b.x, c.x);
    mm.min.z = Math.min(mm.min.z, a.z, b.z, c.z);
    
    mm.max.x = Math.max(mm.max.x, a.x, b.x, c.x);
    mm.max.z = Math.max(mm.max.z, a.z, b.z, c.z);
    
    quad_uvs.push(mm.min.x, mm.min.z, mm.max.x, mm.max.z);
    
}
    
uvs = new Float32Array(quad_uvs);
geometry.setAttribute( 'uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );
    
geometry.setIndex(meshIndex);
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(texture)}));
scene.add(plane);
   
animate();
     
function animate(){
    
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    
}
    
function remapFloat(v_, min0_, max0_, min1_, max1_) { return min1_ + (v_ - min0_) / (max0_ - min0_) * (max1_ - min1_); }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>GLSL Intersection</title>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.116.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.116.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/delaunator@4.0.1/delaunator.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong by generating quad_uvs via triangles. The solution is simpler.

```
for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++){
    
    
    var qx = remapFloat(points[j].x, -512, 512, 1, 0);
    var qz = remapFloat(points[j].z, -512, 512, 0, 1);
    
    quad_uvs.push(...[qx, qz]);
    
}
```

```js
var texture = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
    
    
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, loader, terrain, glsl, uniforms, root, tree;
    
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xDEDEDE);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = "";

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 51200);
camera.position.set(-3072, 2048, -3072);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

controls.minDistance = 8;
controls.maxDistance = 10240;
    
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
    
//simple pseudo quadtree
var points = [], indices = [], quad_uvs = [], groups = [], materials = [];

for(var z = -512; z <= 512; z += 256){
    for(var x = -512; x <= 512; x += 256){
        
        points.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, 0, z));
        
    }  
}
   
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(512, 0, -384));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(128, 0, 512));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(384, 0, 512));
    
//delaunay
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
var indexDelaunay = Delaunator.from(points.map(v => { return [v.x, v.z]; }) );
var meshIndex = [], quad_uvs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < indexDelaunay.triangles.length; i++){ meshIndex.push(indexDelaunay.triangles[i]); }
        
   for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++){


var qx = remapFloat(points[j].x, -512, 512, 1, 0);
var qz = remapFloat(points[j].z, -512, 512, 0, 1);

quad_uvs.push(...[qx, qz]);

}
    
uvs = new Float32Array(quad_uvs);
geometry.setAttribute( 'uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );
    
geometry.setIndex(meshIndex);
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(texture)}));
scene.add(plane);
   
animate();
     
function animate(){
    
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    
}
    
function remapFloat(v_, min0_, max0_, min1_, max1_) { return min1_ + (v_ - min0_) / (max0_ - min0_) * (max1_ - min1_); }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>GLSL Intersection</title>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.116.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.116.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/delaunator@4.0.1/delaunator.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```